# SharePoint Large Upload using MS Graph API - Erroring on second chunk

Tags: powershell, microsoft-graph-api

I am working with PowerShell to upload large files and trying to break the file up into chunks as shown in the documentation. As I understand it when the first chunk uploads successfully (which it does) you will receive a response of nextExpectedRanges. I do get this back but it doesn't match what I had defined initially in the Content-Length header. Instead I get a response back that is the bytes I had uploaded through the end of the file. So I'm trying to figure out what I'm doing wrong and I can't seem to find any good PowerShell examples on this.

The end goal is to be able to use the /createUploadSession and chunk files using PowerShell.

Some examples show not using the Content-Length header so in the code I have provided I have that removed. I still get the same result which is a 400 error on the second chunk I try to upload.

````bsh
Function Invoke-MSGraphUpload {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$FullPath,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$UploadUri)

    Connect-MSGraphAPI
    $AuthHeader = @{
        'Content-Type'  = 'application\json'
        'Authorization' = "Bearer $($global:AuthToken.access_token)"
    }

    $UploadSessionUri = "$($UploadUri):/createUploadSession"
    $Response = Invoke-MSGraphAPIWebRequest -Uri $UploadSessionUri -Method Post -Headers $AuthHeader

    #Fragments
    <#
        https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0
        To upload the file, or a portion of the file, your app makes a PUT request to the uploadUrl value received 
        in the createUploadSession response. You can upload the entire file, or split the file into multiple byte ranges, 
        as long as the maximum bytes in any given request is less than 60 MiB.

        The fragments of the file must be uploaded sequentially in order. Uploading fragments out of order will result in an error.

        Note: If your app splits a file into multiple byte ranges, the size of each byte range MUST be a multiple of 320 KiB (327,680 bytes). 
        Using a fragment size that does not divide evenly by 320 KiB will result in errors committing some files.
    #>

    If ($Response.StatusCode -eq "200") {
        If ((Get-Item $FullPath).Length / 1MB -lt 60) {
            Write-Host "Less than 60MiB"
            $FileBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($FullPath)
            $Header = @{
                'Content-Length' = $($FileBytes.Length)
                'Content-Range'  = "bytes 0-$($FileBytes.Length-1)/$($FileBytes.Length)"
            }
            Invoke-MSGraphAPIWebRequest -Method Put -Uri $Response.uploadUrl -Body $FileBytes -Headers $Header -ContentType "application/octet-stream"
        }
        Else {
            #https://gist.github.com/jehugaleahsa/e23d90f65f378aff9aa254e774b40bc7
            Write-Host "Greater than or equal to 60MiB"
            #$chunkSize = 49152000
            $chunkSize = 320 * 1024 * 4

            $file = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo($FullPath)

            $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($FullPath)
            $count = 0
            $buffer = New-Object Byte[] $chunkSize
            $hasMore = $true

            $lowerByte = 0
            $upperByte = 0

            $output = $buffer

            $bytesRead = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)
            $contentLength = $($output.Length)
            $lowerByte = 0
            $upperByte = ($output.Length - 1)

            $Header = @{
                'Content-Range'  = "bytes $lowerByte-$upperByte/$($file.Length)"
            }
            #'Content-Length' = $contentLength

            Write-Host "------------- Uploading Chunk $count ---------------------" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            Write-Host "Headers: "
            $Header

            $UploadResponse = Invoke-MSGraphAPIWebRequest -Method Put -Uri $Response.uploadUrl -Body $output -Headers $Header -ContentType "application/octet-stream"
            If ($UploadResponse.StatusCode -eq "202") {
                $LowerUploadReponse = ($UploadResponse.nextExpectedRanges -split "-")[0]
                $UpperUploadReponse = ($UploadResponse.nextExpectedRanges -split "-")[1]
                [int]$contentLength = [int]$UpperUploadReponse - [int]$LowerUploadReponse
                $buffer = New-Object Byte[] $contentLength
                $lowerByte = $LowerUploadReponse
                $upperByte = $UpperUploadReponse
                $bytesRead = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, $contentLength)

                while ($UpperUploadReponse) {
                    $count++
                    $Header = @{
                        'Content-Range'  = "bytes $lowerByte-$upperByte/$($file.Length)"
                    }
                    #'Content-Length' = $contentLength

                    $output = $buffer

                    Write-Host "------------- Uploading Chunk $count ---------------------" -ForegroundColor Cyan
                    Write-Host "nextExpectedRanges: $($UploadResponse.nextExpectedRanges)"
                    Write-Host "buffer length: $($buffer.Length)"
                    Write-Host "output length: $($output.Length)"
                    Write-Host "Headers: "
                    $Header

                    $UploadResponse = Invoke-MSGraphAPIWebRequest -Method Put -Uri $Response.uploadUrl -Body $output -Headers $Header -ContentType "application/octet-stream"
                    Invoke-WebRequest -Method Put -Uri $Response.uploadUrl -Body $output -Headers $Header -ContentType "application/octet-stream"

                    $LowerUploadReponse = ($UploadResponse.nextExpectedRanges -split "-")[0]
                    $UpperUploadReponse = ($UploadResponse.nextExpectedRanges -split "-")[1]
                    [int]$contentLength = [int]$UpperUploadReponse - [int]$LowerUploadReponse
                    $buffer = New-Object Byte[] $contentLength
                    $lowerByte = $LowerUploadReponse
                    $upperByte = $UpperUploadReponse

                    $bytesRead = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, $contentLength)
                }

                $reader.Close()
            }
            Else {
                Write-Host "Error uploading file" -ForegroundColor Red
            }
        }
    }
}```
````

Comment: You'll see two additional functions I've written that involve Authentication or Invoking Rest Method. For the most part I just made a wrapper for error handling and returning a bit more information for additional troubleshooting. I've tried stripping that stuff out and just using a straight invoke-webrequest and get the same 400 error on the second chunk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a few more hours of finding things similar to what I wanted to do I finally came upon a working solution.

Got the idea from here: https://github.com/adambu/createuploadsession-graph-jquery/blob/master/App/Scripts/App.js

````
Function Invoke-MSGraphUpload {
    param(
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$FullPath,
        [parameter(Mandatory = $true)]$UploadUri)

    Connect-MSGraphAPI
    $AuthHeader = @{
        'Content-Type'  = 'application/json'
        'Authorization' = "Bearer $($global:AuthToken.access_token)"
    }

    $Checksum = (Get-FileHash -Path $FullPath).Hash

    $Body = @{
        'item' = @{
            '@microsoft.graph.conflictBehavior' = "rename"
        }
    }

    $Body = $Body | ConvertTo-Json -Compress

    $UploadSessionUri = "$($UploadUri):/createUploadSession"
    $Response = Invoke-MSGraphAPIWebRequest -Uri $UploadSessionUri -Method Post -Headers $AuthHeader -Body $Body

    #Fragments
    <#
        https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0
        To upload the file, or a portion of the file, your app makes a PUT request to the uploadUrl value received 
        in the createUploadSession response. You can upload the entire file, or split the file into multiple byte ranges, 
        as long as the maximum bytes in any given request is less than 60 MiB.

        The fragments of the file must be uploaded sequentially in order. Uploading fragments out of order will result in an error.

        Note: If your app splits a file into multiple byte ranges, the size of each byte range MUST be a multiple of 320 KiB (327,680 bytes). 
        Using a fragment size that does not divide evenly by 320 KiB will result in errors committing some files.
    #>

    If ($Response.StatusCode -eq "200") {
        $ChunkSize = 62259200
        $file = New-Object System.IO.FileInfo($FullPath)
        $reader = [System.IO.File]::OpenRead($FullPath)
        $buffer = New-Object -TypeName Byte[] -ArgumentList $ChunkSize
        $position = 0
        $counter = 0
        Write-Host "ChunkSize: $ChunkSize" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        Write-Host "BufferSize: $($buffer.Length)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
        $moreData = $true
        While($moreData) {
            #Read a chunk
            $bytesRead = $reader.Read($buffer, 0, $buffer.Length)
            $output = $buffer
            If($bytesRead -ne $buffer.Length) {
                #no more data to be read
                $moreData = $false
                #shrink the output array to the number of bytes
                $output = New-Object -TypeName Byte[] -ArgumentList $bytesRead
                [Array]::Copy($buffer, $output, $bytesRead)
                Write-Host "no more data" -ForegroundColor Yellow
            }
            #Upload the chunk
            $Header = @{
                'Content-Length' = $($output.Length)
                'Content-Range'  = "bytes $position-$($position + $output.Length - 1)/$($file.Length)"
            }

            Write-Host "Content-Length = $($output.Length)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            Write-Host "Content-Range  = bytes $position-$($position + $output.Length - 1)/$($file.Length)" -ForegroundColor Cyan
            #$position = $position + $output.Length - 1
            $position = $position + $output.Length
            Invoke-MSGraphAPIWebRequest -Method Put -Uri $Response.uploadUrl -Body $output -Headers $Header -ContentType "application/octet-stream"
            #Increment counter
            $counter++
        }
        $reader.Close()
    }
}```
````