# Upload large file to SharePoint Online using Graph API - ContentType error

Tags: powershell, sharepoint, microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, azure-ad-graph-api

I am looking for a way to upload large files (over 4MB) to SharePoint Online using PowerShell and Graph API. I am able to upload files <4MB in size without any problems, but I am struggling with larger files.

I am trying to use [this solution](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/BitTitan.Runbooks.SharePointOnline.Beta/0.2.2/Content/PrivateFunctions%5CUpload-LargeFileToSharePointOnline.ps1) but the following part (line 105, when trying to upload the file) is not working for me:

```
$invokeRestMethodParams = @{
    Uri     = $uploadUrl
    Method  = "PUT"
    Headers = @{
        Accept           = "application/json"
        "Content-Type"   = "text/plain"
        Authorization    = "bearer $($token)"
        "Content-Length" = $fileLength
        "Content-Range"  =  "bytes 0-$($fileLength-1)/$($fileLength)"
    }
    Body = $fileInAscii
}

$response = Invoke-RestMethod @invokeRestMethodParams
```

I keep getting the following error on the *Invoke-RestMethod* (everything else before that works fine):

```
The cmdlet cannot run because the -ContentType parameter is not a valid Content-Type header. Specify a valid Content-Type for -ContentType, then retry. To suppress header validation, supply the -SkipHeaderValidation parameter.
```

If I use the *-SkipHeaderValidation* parameter, I get the following error:

```
Response status code does not indicate success: 400 (Bad Request).
```

I've tried different types of files (they are all less than 10MB) like TXT or PDF, and even different ContentTypes like "application/octet-stream" or "text/plain", but nothing seems to work... I've also tried another solution I found online ([this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57563160/sharepoint-large-upload-using-ms-graph-api-erroring-on-second-chunk?rq=1)), but the error was the same.

Is anyone else experiencing the same, or do you have a script to upload large files (over 4MB) to SharePoint Online using PowerShell AND Graph API?
Thank you so much!

Regards,
Nuno

Comment: Hi, you need to create an upload session to upload large files. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-createuploadsession?view=graph-rest-1.0

Comment: Hi Carl. Thanks, I am aware of that and that part is working fine as I've mentioned (I am able to retrieve the upload URL for the session). The problem is that the actual upload never works...   :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've managed to find a simpler solution that works for files over 3MB (I've also tested 100MB size files). To get the upload URL, I used the code from the solution in my first post.

```
    $fileInBytes = [System.IO.File]::ReadAllBytes($file)
    $fileLength = $fileInBytes.Length

    $invokeRestMethodParams = @{
        Uri     = $uploadUrl
        Method  = "PUT"
        Body    = $fileInBytes
        Headers = @{
            'Content-Range' = "bytes 0-$($fileLength-1)/$fileLength"
        }
    }

    Try {
        $response = Invoke-RestMethod @invokeRestMethodParams -ErrorAction Stop
        Write-Log -Type "INF" -Message "File uploaded to SharePoint Online: '$fileName' ($([Math]::Round($file.length/1MB, 0))MB)"
    } Catch {
        Write-Log -Type "ERR" -Message "Unable to upload '$fileName' to SharePoint Online: '$($_.Exception.Message)'"
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

do you, maybe, know what should I do to get rid of this error:
Exception calling "ExecuteQuery" with "0" argument(s): "Unable to read data from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host."

I am uploading files also 10GB big.. usually encounter the above error after 5GB...
Any idea? I also came across possible issue which could be related to our company VPN..
I already included commands like:
[System.Threading.Timeout]::Infinite
[Net.ServicePointManager]::SecurityProtocol = [Net.SecurityProtocolType]::Tls12
Ty for any help..

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I've changed my procedure and now I am uploading 5GB files instead of 10GB.. And with my script it does work..